# How to call function after page load completed in meteor?

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I am trying to call a function after the response has been sent to the browser, but my template load after the response sent to browser.

```
Template.orders.rendered = function() {
    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
        getTotalOderCount();
    }, 1000);
};
```

This is working fine for me but this function is called after one second . I want to call getTotalOderCount();  when page complete loaded.

Is there a way of getting the function to only be executed after the response has all been sent to the browser?

Comment: What do you mean by "after the response has been sent". Template.myTemplate.rendered or rather use `onRendered` is a callback executed when all Template Data is Rendered in the Browser. U could also use`onCreated`. This is a callback fired when Template Instance is created, so rather before `onRendered`chronologically. I recommand reading: http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-onRendered and following paragraphs. This is really helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to call a method on page load completely and set value in a session  variable. But i am getting null when page load . Because template loaded before to set values in session variable . and when i use Metero.setTimeout function then its working fine.

Comment: are you using publications?

Comment: No i am not using pub/sub i am just calling a method on rendered.

Comment: When are setting the Session Variable in your Code?

Comment: `Template.orders.onCreated(function () {
  Session.set("test", "hello world!);
});
Template.orders.onRendered(function () {
  console.log(Session.get("test"));
});`
This should work